# Start a springboot project for each test case

Tags: spring-boot

We are developing test cases for a micro service using Spring Boot. One of the requirement is that for each Junit test case we need to:

- start the project
- test a unit case and
- then stop the project .

I feel this is an anti pattern, but this is the requirement.

I looked around internet but couldn't find a solution for the same. I was able to start a web server but it provided no response and this might be because the project is not assigned to the server.

Does anyone have any idea on how this can be achieved?

PS: We don't want to use Mockito

Comment: Having to start and stop the project is definitely an anti - pattern. Anyway, apart from that, you probably want to use a tool like Cucumber or Gatling.

Answer (score 1):

Before hand i want to make clear that this a very bad practice and should be avoided. This approach does not implement unit tests concept correctly because you are testing an entire system up, so JUnit wouldn't be the correct tool.

I pocked around and i don't seem to find a Runner that may be able to do this (does not surprise me although), the most similar Runner may be SpringJUnit4ClassRunner which provides you a complete Spring context in your test space, but won't go live with the application.

**An approach i'd suggest if you really want to go with this** is to use tools like REST Assured to do End-to-End API layer tests against the live application, but this implies that you have to find another way to start the app, and then point the REST Assured tests to that started app. Maybe a shell script that starts the app and then starts the REST Assured tests suits, then when the suit ends put down the server.

I highly suggest you to chat with your product/management teams to avoid this kind of stuff since the tests will take FOREVER to run and you will be polluting your local or remote DBs if you are persisting data or other systems through REST or SOAP calls.